# Spring Boot - Angularjs $stateProvider with Security

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

As you know, we can set permissions for specific URLs with spring security. for example

```
.antmatchers("/assets/**").permitall ()
```

My problem is:
I am using the $stateProvider with AngularJS in the project.

So the URL path `Localhost/#/home`, `localhost/#/userList`.

For example, using Security, I want to log in to the `/#/userList` with the `"ADMIN"` authority.

```
.antmatchers("/#/userList").hasauthority("ADMIN")
```

I guess that's not possible. How can we solve this?

Comment: You'll have to do your users authentication and authorization on angular because these URLs with # are angular URLs and not Java Spring. Your java spring app recognizes the part before the #, whatever comes after # is angular related.

Comment: What you think locationprovider html5mode?

Comment: Take a look here (I used it on my app): http://www.stefanoscerra.it/permission-based-auth-system-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this, because the anchor is a client-side concept, see [RFC 1630](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1630.txt):

> A reference to a particular part of a document may, including the
>    fragment identifier, look like
>
> ```
>    http://www.myu.edu/org/admin/people#andy
> ```
>
> in which case the string "#andy" is not sent to the server, but is
>     retained by the client and used when the whole object had been
>     retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Although his is an old thread, still replying so any googler will find this answer- This you can achieve by declaring like this

```java
 .antMatchers("/**/userList").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
```

This worked for me.